# Python indexing a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing

I have a list as below: How do I do index in python. I want to fetch a value for "OS"? Please let me know.

```
[{'UserName': 'd699a1f25d9a3', 'BrowserVersion': None, 'PasswordMinLength': 0, 'SystemAutoLock': 0, 'OS': 'Windows 7 6.1 Build 7601 : Service Pack 1 64bit'}]
```

Comment: This is a very basic question. You should have searched first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  mylist = [{'UserName': 'd699a1f25d9a3', 'BrowserVersion': None, 'PasswordMinLength': 0, 'SystemAutoLock': 0, 'OS': 'Windows 7 6.1 Build 7601 : Service Pack 1 64bit'}]

  OS = mylist[0]['OS']
  print OS
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your list is stored in variable `my_list`:

```
mylist = [{'UserName': 'd699a1f25d9a3', 'BrowserVersion': None, 'PasswordMinLength': 0, 'SystemAutoLock': 0, 'OS': 'Windows 7 6.1 Build 7601 : Service Pack 1 64bit'}]
```

Since the dictionary is the first element of the list, you can access to it using indexing. Remember that indexes start with `0`:

```
my_list[0] # first element
```

Then you can access to a key in the dictionarie by its corresponding value: `my_dict[key]`. In your case:

```
my_list[0]['OS']
```